# Generating a unique clientIdPrefix in KafkaListener

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, spring-kafka

I have a Spring boot application running a Kafka consumer that consumes messages from a single Topic having two partitions(partition-0 and 1). The application is deployed as a single Kubernetes pod. I have scaled the application and now it's running in two pods.  But the client Id prefix of the consumer running in both pod has the same clientIdPrefix 'client-consumer-0'.

How to generated clientIdPrefix unique to the pod?

Answer (score 4):

Set kafka consumer client.id properties for change consumer client name
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/consumer-configs.html#consumerconfigs_client.id.

You can give property in yml file like below.

```
spring:
  kafka:
    consumer:
      properties:
        client.id: ${KAFKA_CLIENT_ID:unique-kafka-client-name}
```

for create unique value for client id you can use pod info
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/#use-pod-fields-as-values-for-environment-variables

i.e **metadata.uid**

```
  env:
    - name: KAFKA_CLIENT_ID
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.uid
```

Comment: Thanks Omer. I'll give a try